# Register Intent Filter to accept any type of file?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an app that needs to be able to open any type of file from a file manager. Its a file conversion/storage app, so it doesn't matter what type of file it is, I need to accept them all, similar to how DropBox would accept any file.

I can't seem to figure out how to register an app to open any type of file in this way. Here's what I have in my manifest under the relevant activity:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

This doesn't seem to have any affect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing  the host and the pathPattern part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the mimeType.

```
<data android:mimeType="*/*" />
```

You can probably remove the pathPattern when matching the mimeType to all.